# Devise mailer custom domain from option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Given that `request` object is not working in `ActionMailer`, is there a way to detect current URL and set `from` option for custom devise mailer controller?

So this is what I have so far in `application_controller.rb`:

```
  before_filter :images, :hide_sidebar, :global_vars, :set_mailer_host
  before_action :sidebar_menu

  def set_mailer_host
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
    @host = request.env['HTTP_HOST'] unless request.env['HTTP_HOST'].include? 'localhost'
  end
```

Devise Mailer custom class:

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer   
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    if record.events.present?
        name = record.events.last.name
        @event = name
    else
        name = "#{record.first_name},"
    end
    opts[:from] = "noreply@#{@host}" if @host
    opts[:subject] ="#{name} Registration - Confirmation Required"
    super
  end
end
```

Also in Devise.rb I've set below:

```
config.mailer = 'DeviseMailer'
```

I don't know why I'm still getting default domain instead of the current URL.

Since I have multiple urls pointing to the same application, is there a way to detect this and configure for Devise Mailers?

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you pass the host as argument to your mailer?

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={}, host)
    ...
end

DeviseMailer.confirmation_instructions(..., @host).deliver
```

Comment: hi, from which controller would I pass as an argument? I'm afraid it might be called twice and also first three params get overwritten